# Make Typescript require a certain set of strings in Interface. Then select that string via form Input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In my project I need searchFilters.order_by to be explicitly one or the other, as defined by my interface. This works. The problem arises when I try and have the user select it via a HTML form select tool.

This gives me the error

> `"Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"date_created" | "date_updated"'."`

```
interface ISearchFilters {
  primary: string,
  when: string,
  date: null|string,
  order_by: 'date_created'|'date_updated',
  sort: string,
}
```

JSX:

```
        Order By:
        <select onChange={(e)=>setSearchFilters({...searchFilters,order_by:e.target.value})}>
          <option value='date_created'>Created</option>
          <option value="date_updated">Updated</option>
        </select>
```

How do I have a user select the .order_by parameter with my TS definition like this? Changing its type to 'string' is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `e.target.value` is loosely. If you can not change that, then you need to type assert it e.g.

```
 order_by: e.target.value as 'date_created' | 'date_updated'
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there another solution that does not require me to type out my options every time I have a target.value assignment?

Comment: @Raven You would need to change the callback type of the `onChange` function. That would be more of a hassle than straight up type asserting.

Comment: @Raven. You can declare types:
`type OrderByDate = 'date_created' | 'date_updated';`
and then use `OrderByDate` as type.